# Can you help me understand why there is a $h^d$ but not h in parzen window

Tags: pattern-recognition

[image]
Is that because x is d dimension. And when we do the change of variable, we have to do that?
this is where my question comes from:
[How to show that the general parzen window provides a probability distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190626/how-to-show-that-the-general-parzen-window-provides-a-probability-distribution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is because of the dimension.

Basically, what you're doing is a [variable substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) $\mathbf{u} = (\mathbf{x - x_i})/h$, so the Jacobian is $h^{-d}$.